# What does it mean when I see a lock in sys.dm_tran_locks and there's no matching row in sys.dm_exec_requests?

Tags: sql-server, locking, azure-sql-database

I'm running this query

```
select sessions.session_id from
   sys.dm_tran_locks locks inner join  sys.dm_exec_sessions sessions
      on locks.request_session_id=sessions.session_id
```

and it consistently outputs around four thousand rows. Yet when I run

```
select session_id from sys.dm_exec_requests
```

it outputs no more than several rows. And if I try this

```
select sessions.session_id, requests.session_id
    from sys.dm_tran_locks locks inner join sys.dm_exec_sessions sessions
       on locks.request_session_id=sessions.session_id
       left outer join sys.dm_exec_requests requests
         on sessions.session_id=requests.session_id
order by requests.session_id
```

I see that none of `sessions.session_id` are null but notably more than half of `requests.session_id` are null.

What does that mean? Where do those rows in `sys.dm_tran_locks` belong than I cannot find a matching row in `sys.dm_exec_requests`?

Comment: How many records after applying extra filter of locks.resource_database_id > 4 ?

Comment: @aasim.abdullah: Same amount as without the filer (I compute `count(*)` and `sum(case when locks.resource_database_id > 4 then 1 else 0 end)` in the same query and they are equal).

Comment: You can hold locks without actively running a query... is your app using an ORM or roll-your-own optimistic concurrency?

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Some queries originate from Ling-to-Sql, others are being run using `SqlCommand` class. I'm not sure but it looks like there're no tweaks to concurrency beyond the default settings.

Answer (score 1):

Two more additional filters are necessary for your first query.

1- You need to execute query for user databases only i.e. `resource_database_id > 4`
and
2- Session status "sleeping" mean, session is currently running no request, so exclude such sessions from your result. i.e. `[sessions].status  <>'Sleeping'`

```
select sessions.session_id,* from
   sys.dm_tran_locks locks inner join  sys.dm_exec_sessions sessions
      on locks.request_session_id=sessions.session_id
WHERE locks.resource_database_id > 4  
AND [sessions].status  <>'Sleeping'
```

Comment: Emm... How is it possible that a session is sleeping and there's a row in locks for that session?

Comment: Yes,  If the client has an open transaction and the client did not submit a commit or rollback command the state is sleeping / awaiting command. see this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/psssql/archive/2008/04/21/how-it-works-what-is-a-sleeping-awaiting-command-session.aspx